# how to modify the number of parallel compilation with Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, build, parallel-processing

How to change the number of parallel compilations when building a C++ project with XCode ?

I am not talking about distributed builds, but on simultaneous compilations of a set of source files from a single project, on a single computer.
(currently using Xcode 3.2.4)

Thanks

Comment: For information, builds were far too long on my Quad Core. After decreasing this value from 8 to 4, build time became much more reasonnable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Adjust the `PBXNumberOfParallelBuildSubtasks` user default, for example:

```
defaults write com.apple.XCode PBXNumberOfParallelBuildSubtasks 6
```

Answer (score 21):

For Xcode 4 you must set the IDEBuildOperationMaxNumberOfConcurrentCompileTasks user default, for example:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEBuildOperationMaxNumberOfConcurrentCompileTasks 4
```

Note the "dt".  This won't affect xcodebuild on the command line.  To do that, use something like

```
xcodebuild -IDEBuildOperationMaxNumberOfConcurrentCompileTasks=4 ...
```

(See http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2011/Apr/msg00403.html and http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2011/Jul//msg00377.html )

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record - developers at our site using XCode 4 discovered that parallel compilation gets disabled if McAfee anti-virus is installed.  Builds that should finish in 15-20 minutes took nearly five hours until McAfee was removed.

Comment: It's probably not that parallel builds are disabled but access is so slow becuase McAfee blocks. I have seen that on Win + OSX also with Avira Antivirus, up to non-writable files because they were locked by the watcher.

Answer (score 1):

For command line builds, I've tested the [2011/Jul mailing list post](http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2011/Jul//msg00377.html) that Mimika linked, and deployed it on our (Xcode 4.2, on Snow Leopard) build server to save memory like so:

```
defaults write xcodebuild IDEBuildOperationMaxNumberOfConcurrentCompileTasks 1
```

Comment: After boot, Xcode 6 will use all four of my iMac's processors, but after a while it uses only two. What makes it fall back to two? Does "defaults write xcodebuild IDEBuildOperationMaxNumberOfConcurrentCompileTasks 1" still work in Xcode 6? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it drops from four to two, but I also found that quitting Xcode 6, then in Terminal entering "defaults write xcodebuild IDEBuildOperationMaxNumberOfConcurrentCompileTasks 4" got me back to four when Xcode is restarted.