# Slow Storyboard edition in XCode 4.2

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, storyboard

Using XCode 4.2 to edit a simple App with a TabViewController and 5 tabs. I am just starting the app so there are not too many components in each.

However, just switching from viewing code to view the Storyboard in XCode takes about 1 minute. Any change is that slow... like it is rebuilding the internal hierarchy of all components everytime I touch something.

Have anybody else experienced this? any advise.

Thanks.

Comment: May help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355667/xcode-4-slow-performance

Comment: Thanks, but no. Already checked all the recommendations there. Thanks.

Comment: This has been improved by removing the navigation buttons from the storyboard, and generate them in code. Still sometimes it is slow, but it has improved a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This is a repeat question.  See here: [Xcode 4 - slow performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355667/xcode-4-slow-performance)

If you delete the workspace it should increase your speed.  (It should be the accepted answer to that question).

Source: I've used this answer in the past and it greatly helped.

If not, read up on the answer here for common issues with xcode 4's slow performance: [Why are xcodebuild and Xcode 4.2 so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780663/why-are-xcodebuild-and-xcode-4-2-so-slow/7781175#7781175)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll check it out. Note: I disagree with the "repeat question" (and the -1) - the questions pointed out talk about compiling and editing source code. While I might have been affected by the same causes my source edits normally and the compiling is normal. In my case this is an issue specifically present only in the storyboards.

Comment: I didn't -1 you, for the record.  And also, i don't use story board but the entirety of xcode 4 is slow for reasons in those similar posts.

Comment: Got it... let me check. I'll try to find out the reasons of my case. I'll comment here if lucky.

Comment: well.. after trying: deleting the workspace did nothing for me. Other alternatives suggested like creating the RAM disk or using 32bit for XCode might have helped maybe a little bit (so little that is hard to measure). I guess we'll have to get used... thanks. :(